# Why doesn't razorengine render this as raw?

Tags: c#, razorengine

I am creating data driven xaml using RazorEngine.

However, I cannot get this to work:

```
string template = "<k t=\" @Raw(Model.Name) \" ";
var model = new { Name = "CS&#10;" };
string result = Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

this causes "result" to become

```
<k t="CS&amp;#10; "
```

I do not want the "&" to be turned into

```
@amp;
```

If I remove any of the following:

the starting character "<"
the space between "k" and "t"
the \"

....then the razor engine parser Raw() function is behaving correctly by not converting "&" into "&"

I was also thinking that I could help Razor understand my intent better by using a code block @{} instead of just @. 
However, I haven't figured how I can make a code block emit text to Razor output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything `&amp;` is actually `&`.

if you try this code you will see that it outputs `&`

```
var str = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&amp;")
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML for more info.

Comment: HttpUtility is part of MVC. This is RazorEngine. Since the text "&amp;" is not the same text as "&", it affects my application. The output stream in my case is not html.

Comment: @Tormod HttpUtility is not for a specific application type. I tested it for example in Console App before posting. But if you like use `System.Net.WebUtility`. It has the same method.

Comment: RazorEngine is a codeplex project. The MVC and HttpUtility classes are not referenced by it. Hence, it doesn't understand inline code that try to use these classes. If you get razorengine through NuGet, and run my code, you'll see that HttpUtility cannot be used. The problem is not getting a string representation with "&" in the Model. The problem is that Razor insists on rendering it using html encoding.